# What is the best way to pass data from pageA to pageE

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I understand if we want to pass data from pageA to pageB, we can use this

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, PageB.ROUTE,arguments:pageAData);
```

If we want to pass data from pageA to pageE, what are the best way to achieve it?

In my app, it has a submit button in pageE. Once it is clicked, I want all data(pageA to pageD) submitted to server.

Comment: Try inherited widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html Note that the widget should wrap your navigator to work in this case as you are changing pages

Comment: @AfridiKayal I using bloc, but how to work with InheritedWidget?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use some state management lib like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [bloc_pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_pattern)

Comment: I using bloc, but how to work with InheritedWidget?

Comment: And RiverPod, the heir apparent too Provider.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to study about state management.

You can use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get), which provides, State Manager, Navigation Manager and Dependencies Manager.

In my opinion, it is the simplest for you to learn to use,

But you can find more approaches here: [List of state management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Choose the best one for your need :)

Comment: And RiverPod isn't in that list yet, but may be soon.

Answer (score 0):

use any state management from the following
Provider
BolC
Redux
GetX
etc